# appending key value to a list from a data frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

i have a data frame  imported into R like this:

```
location<-

          cns  random
char1      1      2
not_char1  3      2
char2      7      10
not_char2  5       2
```

i want to split this data frame in 2X2 contingency tables, calculate fisher test and return them as a list :

```
result=(char1=fisher.test.p.value.char1, char2=fisher.test.p.value.char2)
```

i wrote the code like this:

```
location_list=list()
for (item in seq(1,length(rownames(location)),2)){
  df<-location[item:(item+1),]
  result<-fisher.test(df)
  location_list<-c(location_list, rownames(df[1,])=result$p.value}
```

but it gives the following error:

```
Error in source(".../sd_based/r_data_analysis.R") : 
.../sd_based/r_data_analysis.R:11:52: unexpected '='
10:     result<-fisher.test(df)
11:     location_list<-c(location_list,rownames(df[1,])=
```

R lists looks like Python language dictionary, this strategy works in Python but not here. i appreciate if anybody could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some variation on this should work, using `by` to `split` your `data.frame`, applying `fisher.test` and then using `sapply` to extract `"["` your `"p.value"` value:

```
sapply(by(location,sub("not_","",rownames(location)), fisher.test),"[","p.value")
#$char1.p.value
#[1] 1
#
#$char2.p.value
#[1] 0.3707094
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. just one question the "[" at the end is universal sign to get the p-value from the test or is something different for each test?

Comment: and if i want to add the value of each char to the list and get the result like "result=(char1=1,p-value,char2=7,p-value)", how should i modify the code?

Comment: found it , Tnx. learned a lot from your single sentence code.